# CS50 - Validating Credit Card Numbers in C Language

Tags: c, cs50, credit-card, luhn

Taking the CS50 course and need to make a program that, when putting in a credit card number, returns to you if that card is valid, and if that card is American Express, MasterCard, or Visa.

I've looked up multiple Stack Overflow discussions about this topic, mostly with incorporating Luhn's algorithm into C. I ended up compiling a program that, to me, seems fine and should run without any issues. However whenever I put in a credit card number, it always results as Invalid no matter if that card is valid or not.

I read multiple comments from other discussions about getting the CC number as a string, but decided to leave it as a long, mostly because that is what the instructions advise you to do

Could anyone please help me with identifying the issue in my code, this has been a painful process.

UPDATE: Changing "long" to "long long" seemed to work, and the program now works fine, but now when I enter a number from "valid" credit cards other than AMEX, MC, and Visa (e.g. a Discover card), my program doesn't print Invalid and just does nothing. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// AMEX 34, 37; MASTERCARD 51, 52, 53, 54, 55; VISA 4
// 13, 15, or 16 digits
int main(void)
{
    long number = get_long("Credit Card Number: ");
    long cc = number;
    int length = 0;

    // Get length of number
    while (cc > 0)
    {
        cc /= 10;
        length++;
    }

    // Check if length is valid
    if (length != 13 && length != 15 && length != 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    // Get first digits
    long cc1 = number;
    for (int x = 0; x < length - 2; x++)
    {
        cc1 /= 10;
    }
    int firsttwo = cc1;
    int first = cc1 / 10;

    // Checksum; Luhn Algorithm
    long i = number;
    int d;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        d = i % 10;
        sum += d;
        i /= 100;
    }

    long y = number / 10;
    int d2;
    int prod = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        d2 = y % 10;
        prod = d2 * 2;
        if (prod >= 10)
        {
            prod = prod - 9;
        }
        sum2 += prod;
        y /= 100;
    }

    int total = sum + sum2;

    if (total % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    if ((length == 13 || length == 16) && first == 4)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    if(length == 15 && (firsttwo == 34 || firsttwo == 37))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    if(length == 16 && (50 < firsttwo && firsttwo < 56))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add given inputs which fail, and actual vs expected outputs (or crashes).

Comment: Also, try basic debugging... Print values of variables, if younrefuse to use a debugger.

Comment: @hyde: Unfortunately, OP's task is for week 1 of CS50, but CS50 only teaches about debuggers in week 2. :(

Comment: Good old "printf-debugging" doesn't need a real debugger. ;)

Comment: What operating system and compiler are you using? I am asking because your code will not work on Microsoft Windows on most compilers, because a `long` is not large enough on that platform to represent a credit card number. If you are using that platform, you will have to use `long long` instead of `long`.

Comment: Aside: I'll pedantically echo those "other discussions" by saying that the way CS50 instructs you to store a credit card number as an integer is fundamentally flawed. While the individual digits and their positions have mathematical meanings in Luhn's algorithm, a credit card number by itself has no mathematical meaning, and should be stored and handled as a string. This is especially problematic, since CS50 warns using an `int` (32-bit on their system) will be too small, and suggests a `long` (64-bit on their system) - but the minimum width of a `long` on any given system is only 32 bits.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you're right, I did mean to write "leave it as a long". I'm also using VSCode on Windows. Why wouldn't long be large enough to represent a credit card number?

Comment: ... the trap of thinking that a "number" must be an `int` or `long`, and a "character" is  `char`. Card, phone, PIN and house numbers should always be handled and stored as strings. They are not integers, which cannot preserve leading zeros.

Comment: @Oka If I were to store this number as a string, would I need to make any changes to my code below?

Comment: Yep, CS50 strikes again. This program works fine on platforms where `long` can fit a CCN: https://godbolt.org/z/M3T365PGn (test CCNs from [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm)).

Comment: @noah-jawn Well yes, you'd be dealing with strings. You would have to use `get_string`, and use `strlen` to verify the expected length, and then verify the string consists only of digits. After that, you apply Luhn's Algorithm in much the same way it is [described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), which deals with an array of numbers, but here you'd deal with an array of `char`. Know that to convert a digit `char` to an `int` you subtract the character constant `'0'` from it (e.g., `'7' - '0' == 7`).

Comment: @noah-jawn Re: *"Why wouldn't long be large enough to represent a credit card number?"* - because with most compilers on Windows, `long` has a *width* of 4 bytes, or 32 bits of information (think 32 light bulbs). The largest number that can be represented by a *signed* 32-bit integer is `2147483647`. That's 10 digits. The requirements say credit cards can have a length of 13-16 digits. On other systems, a `long` might be 8 bytes, or 64 bits (that's twice as many light bulbs!). The largest number than can be represented by a *signed* 64-bit integer is `9223372036854775807`. That's 19 digits.

Comment: @Oka Ahhh I see. Thank you for your thorough explanation, it was very helpful. So I can resolve this problem by using long long, or does the credit card number need to be stored as a string
?

Comment: @noah-jawn Credit card numbers *should* be stored and handled as strings, in the general sense (see Weather Vane's earlier comment). That said, for a simple program like this, `long long` would be fine (and work on Windows, see: [MSVC data type ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170)). It looks like CS50 does have a [`get_long_long`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_long_long) function.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed my "long"s to "long long"s and now my program runs perfectly. Thank you to everyone that provided me feedback!

Comment: @Oka You're right, but I left it as get_long and the program runs fine for me

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Just edited my post, thank you for the reminder

Comment: @noah-jawn: Yes, I noticed. That is why I have already deleted my comments regarding that formulation.

Comment: You have programmed your program in such a way that it is only able to print "INVALID", "VISA", "AMEX" or "MASTERCARD". If you want it to print something else, such as "UNKNOWN", if neither of these other results are applicable, then I recommend that you change your 4 `if` statements at the end of your program to a chain of `if`...`else if` statements and put an `else { printf( "UNKNOWN" ); }` at the end of the chain. That way, "UNKNOWN" will be printed if nothing else is printed.